# Get the first column of a file and save it into a File

Tags: java, file

I want to extract the first column in a file using the delimiter "," and save it into a new File. 
Output generates this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Extract.main(Extract.java:26)
```

Here is the code that I used butI am not sure if it is correct or not:

```
public class Extract {
    public Extract(){
    }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/home/omar/Téléchargements/nursery.tmp"));
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("pima.txt"));
            String read = null;
            while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
                read = in.readLine();
                String[] splited = read.split(",");
                if (splited.length > 0)
                {
                    out.append(splited[0].toString());
                    out.newLine();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("There was a problem: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        File f = new File("prima.txt");
        f.delete();
        File f2 = new File("pima.tmp");
        f2.renameTo(new File("pima.txt"));
    }
}
```

Comment: which line is line 26?

Comment: you'll have to check if `in` is `null` in the finally-block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the first line, ie  `read = in.readLine();`, from inside your `while()` loop.
The problem is that you are reading the line when you are checking the while condition and inside while loop you are reading a line again (but this time a new line, because readLine not only reads a line but also moves the reading pointer to next line) so you are getting the next line.

Once you are past the end of the file you get `null` instead of a line, that is why you are getting Exception.

Comment: I removed that line a there is no more exception but I got the file empty

Comment: @OmarMasmoudi Though I am not very sure,That may be because you are using "/home/omar/Téléchargements/nursery.tmp" as temporary file but when in the end you are creating new file with temp file you are doing 'File f2 = new File("pima.tmp")' and there is no such file,try 'File f2 = new File("/home/omar/Téléchargements/nursery.tmp")' in the end